# Real time transcoding of multiple RTMP-Streams

Tags: flash, ffmpeg, rtmp, transcoding, transcode

I am very frustrated after talking to many companies doing live-streaming or selling streaming-products and I hope someone could get me to the right direction.

Here is my problem:

We are broadcasting sportevents live to the internet via flash media encoder. 
At the event locations we mostly have just 2 mbit upstream. So at the moment we are streaming with about 1mbit rate. 
But we need also streams for mobile-devices and a stream for users without fast internet. So we want 2 more streams with lower-bitrates, but we can't get this through the 2mbit...
I am looking for a solutiuon which can transcode about a 1mbit (and maybe in the future a 1.5mbit) livestream in to two (or more) lower-bitrate streams. The solution should be scalable, because sometimes we have 7 events at one day on different locations, so there could be 7 input-streams.
I've searched the net for hardware transcoders, but didn't find a stable solution and I've tested also transcoding with ffmpeg, but it seems to get problems with timing and key-frames for bitrate switching.

- Does anyone know a hardware or software solution for this problem?
- Has anyone done something own like that with ffmpeg or other tools on the cloud (amazon ec2 etc.)?

Thanks!
Jan

Comment: there will be a service soon that does this for h264 rtmp streams Ill keep u updated

Comment: Thanks Philipp, but I need a selfhosted solution and so I build my own with gstreamer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've developed an own solution with [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The Helix server and encoder will work together and will stream to all devices at the specified bit rates.

I would reccomend that you can use jw player with bitrate switching for people with less bandwidth the player will detect the network speeds.

We use it on our software and can stream to iphone, blackberry, android, and straight up rtmp for web browsers its very versatile and I havent seen it not work yet.

These are the resellers for helix in the uk. (im the web developer there).

http://www.streaming.co.uk/

Cheers

:-)

Comment: thanks for this advice. I took a look at the documentation of the helix server, but didn't find anything about transcoding :-( Just to be clear: I have one input stream with 1000kbits and I want to deliver one stream with 300kbits, one with 500kbits and one wiht 1000kbits.

Answer (score 0):

The helix server is just the delivery platform. For the actual transcoding the professional version of Helix PRODUCER will do what you want. (the two products work in tandem one for transcoding one for delivery to all platforms).

http://www.realnetworks.com/uploadedFiles/products-services/Producer-Comparison.pdf

Hope this helps. Feel free to ring in and speak to one of our techincal guys about your requirements if you need any more help. Streaming are the uk parters not sure where you are located.

Pete

Comment: Hi Pete,

i talked to our local Real-Reseller and the helix producer accepts only file-input or cam-input and no ip-input.
so, this solution isn't working for us.